# Combining count/max Select conditions into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to combine both these queries into one, so I have one select query to return one row with the table count and max date.  I can't figure out an easy way to do that.  Any ideas?  Thanks

```
select count(*) from ods.ADDRESS

select max(last_modified)
from
(
select
CASE WHEN MODIFY_DT IS NULL THEN CREATE_DT
ELSE MODIFY_DT END AS LAST_MODIFIED
FROM ODS.ADDRESS
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MODIFY_DT IS NULL THEN CREATE_DT ELSE MODIFY_DT END) AS LAST_MODIFIED
FROM ODS.ADDRESS;
```

Note that you don't even need a subquery.  We can also try simplifying the above using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    MAX(COALESCE(MODIFY_DT, CREATE_DT)) AS LAST_MODIFIED
FROM ODS.ADDRESS;
```

Answer (score 3):

Conditional aggregation is one way to do this:

```sql
select COUNT(*), 
       MAX(CASE WHEN MODIFY_DT IS NULL 
                THEN CREATE_DT
                ELSE MODIFY_DT 
           END) AS LAST_MODIFIED
from ODS.ADDRESS a;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, simply combine them :D

```
select count(*), max(
CASE WHEN MODIFY_DT IS NULL THEN CREATE_DT
ELSE MODIFY_DT END ) AS LAST_MODIFIED
  from ods.ADDRESS
```